# RequireJS optimized file returns undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We are trying to minify/obfuscate a js library, so that we can reuse it in other projects. Background info: I have done some js, but i'm new with AMD or requireJS.

Here's a reduced version of the library, retaining only the format:

```
(function (global, factory) {
if ( typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined'){ 
    factory(exports);
}
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){ 
    define(['exports'], factory);
}
else{
    global['SimpleMath'] = factory({}); 
}}(typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : self.window || self.global, 
(function (exports) {

'use strict';

exports.square = function square(value){
    return value * value;
}

exports['square'] = exports.square;

return exports;})));
```

Inside the main.html we have

```
requirejs(['./libs/SimpleMath'], function (smath){
        console.log(smath);
        console.log(require.s.contexts._.defined);
    });
```

This works and we can see the loaded object print out.

Since we wish to optimize/obfuscate the code, we are trying requirejs' optimizer (single js file):

```
node ../../r.js -o name=SimpleMath out=SimpleMath.min.js baseUrl=.
```

And we do get something that looks like a minified file.
However, if now I try to load the minified version with the same method:

```
requirejs(['./libs/SimpleMath.min'], function (smath){
        console.log(smath);
        console.log(require.s.contexts._.defined);
    });
```

we get 'undefined' for the print out instead.

I can't tell if the original code was wrong, or we are not using the optimizer correctly, or we totally got the concept wrong. Any help or pointers is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself in case someone might find it useful: The minified file was exporting a named module like this

```
define('SimpleMath',['exports'],t)..
```

we had to either

1. load it as a named module with require.config or,
2. make it anonymous, which seems to be the recommended option for our case.

Comment: This is the same case as for `jQuery`, it also defines itself as named module :)